# Given a set of points encoded as matrix $X$, express $XX^T$ in terms of their distance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix $dists$ contains the pairwise distances between $312$ cities and therfore is of size $312 \times 312$: $dists(i,j) = \|x_i - x_j\|$ where $x_i \in \Bbb R^2 \ \forall 1 \le i \le 312$ and $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Let $X \in \Bbb R ^{312 \times 2}$ be a matrix whose $i$th row is $x_i$. Find an expression for $X X^T$ in terms of the matrix $dists$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

You are given that $\texttt{dists}(i,j) = \|x_i - x_j\|$. Thus,

$$
(\texttt{dists}(i,j))^2 = \|x_i - x_j\|^2 = (x_i-x_j)^T(x_i-x_j) = \|x_i\|^2 + \|x_j\|^2 - 2 x_i^Tx_j
$$

Since the $ij$th element of $XX^T$ is equal to $x_i^Tx_j$, it follows that

$$
(XX^T)_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(\|x_i\|^2 + \|x_j\|^2 - (\texttt{dists}(i,j))^2)
$$